# Updating a Rails Model From JS Event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been looking around and cannot seem to find out if it is common practice to update a Rails model attribute from a JS callback.

In one of my views I have a datepicker that sends a callback once the value has been changed. I would like to save this date to the current model "date" attribute.

```
$('#datetimepicker4').on('dp.change', function (e) {
  // SAVE THIS VALUE TO SPECIFIED MODEL ATTRIBUTE HERE
});
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: This is common practice, Ended up getting it working with the following ajax put request.

```
  $.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  dataType: "script",
  url: '/thread/27',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify({ thread:{id:27, title:"blaaahhh title"}, _method:'put' })
  }).done(function( msg )
      {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've done much research beforehand, because this is a very common thing to do.

Your terminology is also wrong. You're not changing anything in the model. You're simply POSTing a value to your database. Do some research on [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp) and then ask a more detailed, but concise question.

There's nothing wrong with being a beginner, but please do research beforehand, and then create a Stack Overflow question only if that research has led to dead ends. Then create a question featuring what you already know and where you're stuck.